# enablePermanentHighlight in esri Feature Layer

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, esri, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

```
let marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(lat, lon), { icon: markerIcon });
map.addLayer(marker);
```

Just like the normal marker, how can we use `enablePermanentHighlight()` on features of `FeatureLayer`. Any alternative?

This is how I use this on marker,

```
marker.enablePermanentHighlight();
```

or

```
marker.options.highlight = "permanent";
```

I have used the same method on feature layer, but that layer was not highlighting/blinking.

```
foundFeatureLayer.eachActiveFeature((layer) => {
    if (layer.feature || layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        layer.enablePermanentHighlight();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `enablePermanentHighlight` function in Leaflet core. Can you please link to the documentation on this function?

Comment: Its a package, I want to know anything similar to [this](https://github.com/brandonxiang/leaflet.marker.highlight)

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait for your `featureLayer` to load before you can loop through individual features.

```
fl.on("load", function (e) {
  fl.eachActiveFeature((layer) => {
    if (layer.feature || layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        layer.enablePermanentHighlight();
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/nuxawek/edit?html,output